# Smooth Infinite Scrolling Banner [CSS Only]

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

Looking to optimize this infinite scrolling effect, however I'm not entirely sure how to create a smooth transition when looping back to the original image. At 10s it's hardly noticeable, however at 30s it's more evident. I'm assuming it has something to do with the ending position margin, but can't quite pinpoint it. What should the value of the last frame be?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wb28eeh2/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="photobanner">
        <img class="first" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="photobanner">
        <img class="second" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="photobanner">
        <img class="first" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: white;
}

.photobanner, .photobanner2 {
    height: 233px;
    width: 3550px;
}

.photobanner img, .photobanner2 img {
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 233px;
    width: 350px;
}

.photobanner img  {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.photobanner img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
/*keyframe animations*/
.first {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2125px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2125px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2125px;}
}

@-ms-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2125px;}
}

@-o-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {margin-left: 0px;}
 100% {margin-left: -2125px;}
}

.second {
    -webkit-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermoves 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2125px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes bannermoves {
 0% {margin-left: -2125px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2125px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}

@-ms-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2125px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}

@-o-keyframes "bannermoves" {
 0% {margin-left: -2125px;}
 100% {margin-left: 0px;}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/wb28eeh2/3/.

You had unnecessary space between images (cause `display: inline`, read this article — https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). I set:

```
.photobanner, .photobanner2 {
    font-size: 0
}
```

Then I remove `padding-right: 2px` and set:

```
.photobanner img, .photobanner2 img {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Really space between 2 `img` tags was `6px`, now it's `5px`.

Now we can calculate required `margin-left` for animation: 6 x (350 + 5) = `2130px`. That's it.

Comment: Works great, thanks for the link to that article about the spacing. Interesting solution!

Comment: One follow-up though, for calculating the required margin-left, why 6?

Comment: @MikeReddy `2125px` was in your code. It's `~5,97` blocks width (350 + 6). I just rounded to 6 blocks width = `2130px`.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov may I know from where you are getting the value 6 in the above calculation, which you are multiplying.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov I am facing the issue with same kind of scenario, first scroll working somewhat better but when it comes to second loop it is not even close. Could you suggest me where I am wrong. This is my [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4d54zqmv/)

Comment: @Benjamin I think you should create another question for your case.

Comment: @Sergey Denisov What if there are only 5 images?. How to hide the space trail after 1 loop?

Comment: @monisha you could create another question with the problem and your code.